# Ruby one liner to replace a chunky code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Any awesome one liner to get rid of this chunky code here?

```
hash = {}
hash["permission_type"]  = "some permission type"
hash["vaue"] = "some value"
permission_collection = [] << hash
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean ... :)

Comment: Use `permission_collection = [hash]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
permission_collection = [ {"permission_type" => "some permission type", "vaue" => "some value"} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a one-liner:

```
permission_collection = [Hash["permission_type","some_permission_value","value","some_value"]]
```

IMO, the best option would be to use Utsav's answer, but to spread the hash out across multiple lines to make it more readable.

Something like:

```
permission_collection = [
                          {
                            "permission_type" => "some_permission_value",
                            "value"           => "some_value"
                           }
                        ]
```

Is more than one line, but plenty more readable.